# Extracting rows from a data frame with respect to the bin value from other data frame(without using column names)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am working with 3 data frames, out of which 2 data frames contains additional bin number assigned to column data based on the range in which they belong (in separate columns).

df_1

A     B

5     6

8     1

6     7

4     9

1     3

9     2

2     5

df_2

A     B     A_bin     B_bin

5     6     2       2

8     1     1       1

6     7     3       2

4     9     3       3

1     3     1       1

9     2     1       1

2     5     2       2

df_3

A     B     C     D     A_bin     B_bin     C_bin     D_bin

5     6     2     6    2       2       1       2

8     1     6     4    1       1       2       2

6     7     3     1    3       2       1       1

4     9     1     9    3       3       1       3

1     3     8     7    1       1       3       3

9     2     4     8    1       1       2       3

2     5     9     2    2       2       3       1

df_1 contain just two columns, df_2 have additional column which contain the bin assigned to column A and B according to the range in which the belong, similarly, df_3 contains columns with values and additional column with bin number assigned.

I want to extract the rows from df_3 such that it only extract data where df_2 columns have bin value "2" for each column respectively in a separate data frame.

The Main problem i am facing is to do it **WITHOUT** mentioning the column names anywhere in the code.

expected output

df_output_1 (where bin values for column 'A' in df_2 is 2)

A     B     C     D

5     6     2     6

2     5     9     2

df_output_2 (where bin values for column 'B' in df_2 is 2)

A     B     C     D

5     6     2     6

6     7     3     1

2     5     9     2

Comment: Do you use some code for create `df_2` and `df_3` ? Can you share it?

Comment: import numpy as np
       def binner(df_1,num_bins): 
        for c in df_1.columns: cbins = np.linspace(min(df_1[c]),max(df_1[c]),num_bins) df_1[c + '_binn'] = np.digitize(df_1[c],cbins)
 return df_1 df_2=binner(df_1,3)    
@jezrael this is how i converted df_1 to df_2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using merging (right or left) we can filter the data fame.

```
    for bin_name in (column_name + "_bin" for column_name in df_1_columns):
      print(bin_name)
      df_3_joined = pd.merge(df_3[df_3_op_columns], df_2[df_2[bin_name] == 2][df_1_columns], how='right', on=df_1_columns, suffixes=['_l', ''])
      print(df_3_joined)
```

Complete example is

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A', 'B'])
df_1.loc[len(df_1)] = [5,6]
df_1.loc[len(df_1)] = [8, 1]
df_1.loc[len(df_1)] = [6, 7]
df_1.loc[len(df_1)] = [4, 9]
df_1.loc[len(df_1)] = [1, 3]
df_1.loc[len(df_1)] = [9, 2]
df_1.loc[len(df_1)] = [2, 5]

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A', 'B', 'A_bin', 'B_bin'])
df_2.loc[len(df_2)] = [5, 6, 2, 2]
df_2.loc[len(df_2)] = [8, 1, 1, 1]
df_2.loc[len(df_2)] = [6, 7, 3, 2]
df_2.loc[len(df_2)] = [4, 9, 3, 3]
df_2.loc[len(df_2)] = [1, 3, 1, 1]
df_2.loc[len(df_2)] = [9, 2, 1, 1]
df_2.loc[len(df_2)] = [2, 5, 2, 2]

df_3 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A_bin', 'B_bin', 'C_bin', 'D_bin'])
df_3.loc[len(df_3)] = [5, 6, 2, 6, 2, 2, 1, 2]
df_3.loc[len(df_3)] = [8, 1, 6, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2]
df_3.loc[len(df_3)] = [6, 7, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1]
df_3.loc[len(df_3)] = [4, 9, 1, 9, 3, 3, 1, 3]
df_3.loc[len(df_3)] = [1, 3, 8, 7, 1, 1, 3, 3]
df_3.loc[len(df_3)] = [9, 2, 4, 8, 1, 1, 2, 3]
df_3.loc[len(df_3)] = [2, 5, 9, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1]

results = {}
df_1_columns = list(df_1.columns)
df_3_op_columns = [cname for cname in list(df_3.columns) if not cname.endswith("_bin")]
for bin_name in (column_name + "_bin" for column_name in df_1_columns):
    df_3_joined = pd.merge(df_3[df_3_op_columns], df_2[df_2[bin_name] == 2][df_1_columns], how='right', on=df_1_columns)
    results[bin_name] = df_3_joined

for binName, result in results.iteritems():
    print(binName)
    print(result)
```

If you know the bin names, then retrieve the result as follows.

```
A_bin_df = results['A_bin']
print(A_bin_df)
B_bin_df = results['B_bin']
print(B_bin_df)
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot. But, when applying to a larger data set it is causing confusion. This is printing A_bin and B_bin below each other. And when printing df_3_joined outside the function ,it is only printing according to only 2nd column (B_bins). Is there a way to store rows of a each data column with bin=2 in a separate data frame respectively? @Xpeditions

Comment: Yes, we can. One option is use a dictionary and store the results into it. `results = {}` and in for loop `results[bin_name] = df_3_joined`

Comment: @ Xpeditions dictionary is the right way and even it canframe  be converted into a data frame, but is can we retrieve binName with its result separately in the form of a dictionary or a data frame ,so that each dataframe can be used individually .Here, while retrieving result it displays the most recent stored value i.e b_bin and using append didn't worked well for me. @ Xpeditions

Comment: Can you please share the code you tried ? also the required output ?

Comment: i tried your code with adding a result in a data frame, but the data frame is only displaying for B_bins and not A_bins. Your code is giving the desired output but i am not able to retrieve A_bin and B_bin in separate data frame...please help @Xpeditions

Comment: All are separate dataframes, If you know the bin names, then you can get it `A_bin_df = results['A_bin']

print(A_bin_df)

B_bin_df = results['B_bin']

print(B_bin_df)`

I have updated the example also.

Comment: but here you are using column name (i cant use column name), and what if some other data frame is provided (with more bin columns like C_bin, D_bin and so on)? will this code still save the result in separate dataframe ..no matter what is the number of columns?

Comment: This code will work for any number for _bin columns. Also the results are stored in separate dataframe. If you could update the questions with your code, I would update my sample also.

Comment: actually i wanted to compare(min,max,median) data of column A and B for when their respective bin columns have value=2 @Xpeditions

Answer (score 1):

Use [df.columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html#pandas.DataFrame.columns) and column index to prevent using **column names**.

You can use `all_cols = df_2.columns` to get a list of column names. 
Then, use `all_cols[i]` to get column names.

For example, you can get *column B* with `df_2[all_cols[1]]` and get *column B_bin* with  `df_2[all_cols[1 + len(all_cols) / 2]]`. If you want to get another column and its corresponding _bin column, just change the "1" to other dataframe column index.

Comment: i am trying to make a template code such that it can run on a data frame even it has 100 columns , to make a template code for any random data frame, a data frame may have any number of column and we might not be aware of the column index. Thus, i guess an iterative approach is to be applied. @高佳翔